# Vue3 Composition API - Pinia store returns "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ____ is not a function"

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

Searched all over SO, very little information.

The store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'
export const useScanStore = defineStore({
    id: 'scan',
    state: () => ({
        scans: [],
        scan : null,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        messages : []
    }),
    getters: {
        getScans : state => state.scans,
    },
    subscriptions: {

    },
    actions: {
        async updateScan(id,data) {
           // code here that works
       }
    // trimmed for shortness
}
```

THE COMPONENT

```
<template>
   <div>
      <q-btn color="orange" text-color="white" size="sm" @click="stopScan" class="q-mr-sm">
                STOP
       </q-btn>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import {useScanStore} from "@/stores/scan";
const scanStore = useScanStore();
// trimmed

async function stopScan(id){
    const rerunResponse = await scanStore.updateScan(id, {status: 'failed'}) //<<< ERROR HERE   
}
</script>
```

The frustrating part is that THIS EXACT code works in other component. So that function DOES exist.
It's imported IDENTICALLY in component where it works.
Error points at that line in function.

Why am I getting this error? I reduced component to just a single function, button and call.

There are NO OTHER ERRORS in console. Just this (when button is pressed):
[image]

Comment: The right syntax for defining a store should be `defineStore('scan', { state: ...})`

Comment: @Duannx - that's weird. I have stores working (this and others) with this type of definition. I am going to try passing ID as a first param.

Also, I restarted, rebuilt and up my docker image and it seems to be working now. Probably was cached?!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up destroying and rebuilding my docker compose (Docker image) and it started working.